# Show data from one specific user that has no in another table in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in mySQL, infoequipo and habitacion.

infoequipo Table:
[image]

habitacion Table:

[image]

I'd like to get information which serialNumber from emailCliente that is not in habitacion table. For exemple:  emailCliente 1 has serialNumbers 123456, BBe47558120dd and bd1c029f2874ea91... but already used bd1c029f2874ea91 and 123456. The query should return just BBe47558120dd. How i can do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `LEFT JOIN`. Please check below query:

```
SELECT a.serialNumber
FROM infoequipo a
LEFT JOIN habitacion b
ON a.serialNumber = b.serialNumber
WHERE b.serialNumber IS NULL
AND emailCliente = '1';
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but it is returning all serialNumbers, I need just from a specific emailClient

Comment: Updated query for specific emailCliente. This query will return results for emailCliente = 1.